# Python community module, restrict size of each community?

Tags: python

I am using the community module (http://perso.crans.org/aynaud/communities/api.html)'s best partition function to detect communities in a graph.

However, some of the communities are highly connected, so the algorithm tends to group them.

I want to separate these communities by setting a maximum size of each community (for example, the algorithm should try and maximize modularity when each community has max size 10).

How can I do this? I honestly am not sure where to start. Should I loop through the dict outputted by the function, and if any communities are larger than a certain size, re-run the algorithm? That is where I am at now.

I am 100% open to alternative ways to detect communities other than this module.

Here is the code for the partition:

```
G = nx.read_graphml(graphfile)
G = nx.Graph(G)
#G = nx.DiGraph.to_undirected(G)

#finds best community using louvain
partition = community.best_partition(G)

#adds partition/community number as attribute named 'modularitygroup'
for n,d in G.nodes_iter(data=True):
    d['group'] = partition[n]
```