# number or size of python igraph communities

Tags: python, python-2.7, igraph

I am using the python igraph package for community detection. Currently, I am using `community_multilevel`

```
communities = ig.Graph.community_multilevel(g)
```

However, the detected communities are too large, making them less informative. Is there a way to either specify the number of communities or restrict the size of the communities so they are smaller? I am not opposed to using other community detection algorithms available in igraph.

I know there was a similar question asked here: [Python community module, restrict size of each community?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342212/python-community-module-restrict-size-of-each-community), but it was never answered. I appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to either specify the number of communities or restrict the size of the communities so they are smaller?

The answer is pretty disappointing: no, there isn't; none of the community detection algorithms in igraph let you specify the number of communities in advance or restrict their sizes.